# manipulation of date fields in multiple file using bash in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

We have some | delimited input CSV files.  Our requirement is if last field value contains 9999-12-31 then we need to subtract 3 days from 2nd last field and keep the last field as it is.  And if last field value does not have 9999-12-31 then subtract 3 days from both last and second last field.

Sample Input file:-

```
#Code|sequence|Code_ID|margin_ID|Eff_date|End_date
M|X19|0002|F3|2020-12-10|9999-12-31
M|X19|0002|F3|2021-01-15|9999-12-31
M|X19|0002|F3|2010-10-10|2019-11-09
M|X19|0002|F3|2010-03-09|2011-04-02
```

Expected Output file:-

```
#Code|sequence|Code_ID|margin_ID|Eff_date|End_date
M|X19|0002|F3|2020-12-07|9999-12-31
M|X19|0002|F3|2021-01-12|9999-12-31
M|X19|0002|F3|2010-10-07|2019-11-06
M|X19|0002|F3|2010-03-06|2011-03-30
```

Can anyone suggest with script or command to get the expected output?

I am trying with the following command, but getting error.

```
for i in `ls *.csv`
do
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{if(NR>1) { if ($NF~/9999-12-31/) { $(NF-1)="date -d \"$(date -d \""$(NF-1)"\")-3days\" \"+%Y-%m-%d \""; print $0} 
else {$(NF-1)="date -d \"$(date -d \""$(NF-1)"\")-3days\" \"+%Y-%m-%d \""; $NF="date -d \"$(date -d \""$NF"\")-3days\" \"+%Y-%m-%d \""; 
print $0} } }' $i >> temp/new_$i
done
```

Getting awk: syntax error near line 1

---

EDIT by Ed Morton I ran the above awk script through `gawk -o-` (pretty-print) to make it legible and here is the vastly clearer result:

```
{
    if (NR > 1) {
        if ($NF ~ /9999-12-31/) {
            $(NF - 1) = "date -d \"$(date -d \"" $(NF - 1) "\")-3days\" \"+%Y-%m-%d \""
            print $0
        } else {
            $(NF - 1) = "date -d \"$(date -d \"" $(NF - 1) "\")-3days\" \"+%Y-%m-%d \""
            $NF = "date -d \"$(date -d \"" $NF "\")-3days\" \"+%Y-%m-%d \""
            print $0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first step to fixing the 'syntax error near line 1` is to write the script so it occupies multiple lines so it is somewhat readable.  As it stands, it is close to completely inscrutable because it is unreadable.

Comment: Cramming a large script onto 1 line is always a bad idea for many reasons, one of them being that every error message you get will always tell you the error is on line 1 which isn't useful. Having said that - your script doesn't contain any syntax errors so either you didn't post the script you ran or there are problems in the calling shell script or your awk is broken (e.g. make it's old, broken awk - /bin/awk on Solaris).

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT:*** With function approach in `awk` try following. Written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`. I have run this on single file we can also pass csv files into this program without using bash loop.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  threedaysSecs=(3 * 24 * 60 * 60)
  FS=OFS="|"
}
function getDate(field){
    value=(mktime(substr($field,1,4)" "substr($field,6,2)" "substr($field,9,2) " 00 00 00"))-threedaysSecs
    $field=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", value)
}
$NF=="9999-12-31"{
  getDate((NF-1))
}
$NF!="9999-12-31"{
  getDate((NF-1))
  getDate(NF)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following. Without function approach.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  threedaysSecs=(3 * 24 * 60 * 60)
  FS=OFS="|"
}
$NF=="9999-12-31"{
  value=(mktime(substr($5,1,4)" "substr($5,6,2)" "substr($5,9,2) " 00 00 00"))-threedaysSecs
  $5=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", value)
}
$NF!="9999-12-31"{
  value1=(mktime(substr($5,1,4)" "substr($5,6,2)" "substr($5,9,2) " 00 00 00"))-threedaysSecs
  value2=(mktime(substr($6,1,4)" "substr($6,6,2)" "substr($6,9,2) " 00 00 00"))-threedaysSecs
  $(NF-1)=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", value1)
  $NF=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", value2)
}
1
' Input_file
```

Comment: It might be clearer if you wrote `3 * 86400` or even `3 * 24 * 60 * 60` instead of `259200`.    The requirement seems to be 'subtract three days from the 5th (second from last) field (unconditionally), and 'subtract three days from the 6th (last) field if it is not `9999-12-31`.  I think I'd write a function to subtract 3 days from a date, or a function to subtract N days from a date and call it with N=3.  Then conditionally call that function on the last column and unconditionally call it on the second last column.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, sure, function approach is on the way.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk, using `getline` and `date` in shell:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="|"
}
FNR>1{
    for(i=5;i<=5+($5=="9999-12-31");i++)
        if(("date -d \"" $i " -3days\" +\"%Y-%m-%d\"" | getline res)>0)
            $i=res
        else
            exit 1
}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With plain `bash` and `date` from GNU coreutils:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.csv; do
    while IFS='|' read -ra field; do
        if [[ ${field[0]} != \#* ]]; then
            field[-2]=$(date -d "${field[-2]} - 3 days" +%F)
            if [[ ${field[-1]} != '9999-12-31' ]]; then
                field[-1]=$(date -d "${field[-1]} - 3 days" +%F)
            fi
        fi
        (IFS='|'; printf '%s\n' "${field[*]}")
    done < "$file" > "temp/new_$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for date functions (will be orders of magnitude faster than any code calling the Unix `date` command) and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="|"
    deltaSecs = -3*24*60*60
}
NR > 1 {
    $(NF-1) = applyDelta($(NF-1),deltaSecs)
    if ( $NF != "9999-12-31" ) {
        $NF = applyDelta($NF,deltaSecs)
    }
}
{ print }

function applyDelta(date,delta) { return secs2date( date2secs(date) + delta ) }
function date2secs(date) { return mktime(gensub(/-/," ","g",date) " 12 0 0") }
function secs2date(secs) { return strftime("%Y-%m-%d",secs) }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
#Code|sequence|Code_ID|margin_ID|Eff_date|End_date
M|X19|0002|F3|2020-12-07|9999-12-31
M|X19|0002|F3|2021-01-12|9999-12-31
M|X19|0002|F3|2010-10-07|2019-11-06
M|X19|0002|F3|2010-03-06|2011-03-30
```

If you don't have GNU awk but somehow do have GNU date then just change the definition of the final 2 functions above to:

```
function date2secs(date,        cmd, line, secs) {
    cmd = "date +\"%s\" --date=\"" date " 12:00:00\""
    secs = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : -1 )
    close(cmd)
    return secs
}

function secs2date(secs,        cmd, line, date) {
    cmd = "date +\"%Y-%m-%d\" --date=\"@" secs "\""
    date = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : -1 )
    close(cmd)
    return date
}
```

but as mentioned previously it will run much slower than the gawk version as it's spawning a subshell every time it calls `date`.